Difficulty Grasping Weak and Weak-* Topologies and Their Intuition
I've been wrestling with the concepts of weak and weak-* topologies and how they naturally arise in functional analysis. Despite my efforts, they seem to come out of nowhere for me, and I'm hoping to gain some clarity with your insights. Let’s talk about weak topology first.
According to Folland(Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications Page 168)

One often wishes to study the operator $\frac{d}{dx} $, or more complicated operators constructed from it, acting on various spaces of functions. Unfortunately, it is virtually impossible to define norms on most infinite-dimensional functions spaces so that $\frac{d}{dx}$ becomes a bounded operator."

This statement makes sense to me, but I'm struggling to piece everything together. For instance, the concept of a weak derivative kind of feels like we're saying, "Since we're in a framework where we can't distinguish two functions when they coincide almost everywhere (a.e.), let's tweak the notion of derivative to respect this." However, it's not clear to me how a weak derivative becomes bounded when the classical derivative doesn't.
When it comes to different modes of convergence, I can somewhat visualize what's happening. For example, if $f_n \to f$ in $L^1([-1,1])$, it's like saying the average distance between these functions is getting smaller, even though they may differ on a set of measure zero. This kind of intuition works for me for other types of convergence (like in measure, pointwise, almost everywhere pointwise, uniform, almost everywhere uniform, etc.).
But when someone says $f_n \to f$ in the weak topology, I'm lost. I can't intuitively grasp what's actually happening.
Moving on to weak-* convergence, I understand it as a way to naturally embed a Banach space $X$(or make it isomorphic to a subset) into $X^{**}$, its double dual. Sure, it's neat that $X$ lies within $X^{**}$, aligning with our intuitions from finite-dimensional spaces, but I'm questioning if there's more to it. Is there a deeper insight I'm missing?
I've been stuck on this for a while and would greatly appreciate any explanations or insights you could share.
Thank you very much!
P.S:I highly recommend you to use $d/dx$ as an example, especially in solving differential equations since it seems to me a key example.

When you first met continuous functions, you would have $f$ is continuous when $\displaystyle \lim_{x_i\to x}f(x_i)=f(x)$. The weak*-topology on $X^{}$ is such that it makes each element $f\in X$ continuous in the above sense $\displaystyle \lim_{x_i\to x}f(x_i)=f(x)$. Here the $(x_i)$ is a net in $X^$ and $f(x_i):=x_i(f)$ is using $X\hookrightarrow X^{**}$.

@JPMcCarthy Thanks for responding! Yes I understand that we're making the subset of $X^{**}$ corresponding to $X$ continuous. What I do not understand is why should I do that? What's the problem I'm overcoming?

This line of thought helped me to get some intuition about weak* topology: A space is compact iff every open cover of that space has a finite subcover. Compactness is often a desirable property. Intuitively, if you have a lot of open sets, it will be more difficult to find a finite subcover; if you have finitely many open sets, you will always find a finite subcover. The weak* topology is weaker than the weak topology, which again is weaker than the strong topology. So we likely find sets that are compact in the weak* topology but not in the strong topology. This carries over to many other 1/

topological properties like continuity or convergence. 2/2

@SydAmerikaner Thanks for your attention! Yes you are correct about compactness and how it is related with topology being fine . But there are infinitely many other topologies(weaker than the topology induced by operator norm) one can consider. What is specific about this one?

What is nice about the weak topology is that, in reflexive spaces, closed and bounded sets are compact with respect to the weak topology. Moreover, see Alaoglou theorem

@KhaledAlekasir certainly, there are many topologies to study (e.g., SOT). However, there are a lot of nice properties that make studying this particular topology worthwhile. Considering all these properties individually may not seem interesting enough, but the collection of properties is. For me, the fact that it is weaker than the strong topology + the fact it arises naturally in some sense made me accept it that it's a nice topology to study (and is probably the reason it's so present).

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thank you very much for your attention Evan! Yes I know already that the closed ball is closed in weak* topology due to  Alaoglou theorem and I understand that this is very nice to have such quality (which kinda makes infinite dimensional spaces act like $R^n$) but what I'm trying to understand is if I lived say 100 years ago and I didn't know anything about weak* topology, what was the way I needed to take to come to "oh I see I need this definition, it should solve the problem!" what is the  problem that this definition is solving for me?

@SydAmerikaner you mentioned this topology arises naturally. I'd really appreciate if you elaborate. for example in the case $d/dx$?

I would say that studying topologies that are generated by a family of functions $\mathcal F$ is an interesting topic on its own. (This is the smallest topology with the property that each function $f \in \mathcal F$ is continuous).
For example, the product topology on $\prod_i X_i$ is the topology generated by the projections $π_i \colon X \to X_i$.
When dealing with a vector space $X$, the first thing that comes in mind is taking $\mathcal F = X^*$ (the dual). This is the weak topology. This should give the motivation to delve deeper and examine the interesting properties of the topology.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thanks for your help, your projection example was very helpful actually and made it more clear to that what is going on. That would be really nice if you give several examples and explain them in more details, specially $d/dx$ example and also my question on it's meaning in probability theory here

@EvangelopoulosFoivos you mentioning projections actually reminded me sth. Stein mentions in his book functional analysis(chapter 1, exercise 6 or 7) that one of the illustrating examples is considering $f_n(x) = sin(nx)$ which doesn't converge (say in $L^2$) but it actually converges weakly to zero in $L^2$ (due to Riemann-Lebesgue lemma). I guess maybe this has sth to do with  projections, since $sin(nx)$ and $cos(nx)$ can be considered as a basis for $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$

It seems to me there are two different questions here:

How does one get to the notion of weak derivative,
How does one get to the notion of weak/(weak$^*$) topology and what is the intuition behind this convergence.

Now, let's try to get an intuition for $1$. Instead
of working directly with differential operators, let's start with a minimization problem in calculus of variations:
The setting: a bounded open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary.
Say we want to optimize something like
$$I(u):=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^2dx,$$
where $u$ should be a smooth function that is equal to a function $g$ on the boundary of $\Omega$ (let's ignore the second condition for a moment).
First, let us proceed only formally: to find stationary points, we want to have something like
$$ 0=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac1t(I(u+t\varphi)-I(u))=2\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla \varphi=-2\int \Delta u \varphi=-2\int_{\Omega}u\Delta \varphi,$$
where $\varphi$ is a smooth function with support contained in $\Omega$. Notice that the RHS is defined for a larger class of functions than $C^\infty(\Omega)$: this is very useful, since finding minimizers is easier in a larger space. Hence we already have the intuition that we should try to extend our space from smooth functions to something more general, where the RHs makes sense.
Now let's do something more precise:
Since we want to minimize $I(u)$, it makes sense that we want to try and
find a topology that makes $I$ into a continuous function. The easiest suggestion is also the right one: let's just use the norm $\|u\|=\|u\|_{L^2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ on the spae $C^\infty(\Omega)$. There is, however, one big issue: the space is not complete, which is a nontrivial obstacle if we want to try to find the minimizer of $I$ (and not just take an $\inf$). Let's just take the completion of this space then, call it $H$. It is clear that $\nabla$ admits an extension as a continuous operator to $\nabla: H\to L^2$. How does it behave? Well, exactly as it should based on the intuition above:
$$\int (\partial_{x_i} f) \varphi=-\int f \partial_{x_i}\varphi,$$
where $\varphi$ is the same kind of bump function as above. Some work proves that the two definitions are actually equivalent: that is, the norm extension of $\nabla$ is exactly the weak definition. This is how the weak derivative
comes into play in analysis (or at least, in calculus of variations): we are mostly interested in seeing how $\nabla u$ interacts (via pairing) with bump functions, hence the weak derivative definition.
Now that we have the definition of weak derivative, let's try to get an intuition for the weak topology. Well, since we want to minimize $I$ on
$X:=\{f\in H: Tr(f)=g\}$ (I haven't defined the trace operator: just think of it as the norm extension of the boundary restriction operator on $C^\infty$$^1$), which by the Poincarè inequality is contained in some ball of $H$, there's an idea that looks rather interesting: if the ball were compact and $X$ closed, then the minimum would be very easy to get. Now $X$ is closed (since $Tr$ is continuous), but the ball is not compact in the norm topology. Hence we need another topology on $H$ which makes balls into compact sets. It cannot be stronger than the norm topology but we would still like it to be
related to it, so let's look for a weaker topology that turns balls into compact sets. But wait, if we turn to a weaker topology, how can we be sure that $I$ is continuous? Well, we can't, but we don't really need that. It suffices for $I$ to be semicontinuous; and a function is semicontinuous if it's the supremum of continuous functions. Since $I$ is convex, it's the supremum of a family of linear functionals on $H$, which already
nudges us in the right direction: we want a topology that makes the balls compact and that keeps every element of $H'$ continuous. And it's easy to see that that is just the weak topology. (This line of reasoning is the basis of the direct method in calculus of variations).
I've cheated a little bit here, since my space is reflexive so there is no difference between $w$ and $w^*$ topologies. But the intuition remains the same in general, with the caveat that I cannot have all three properties at once:

weaker than norm topology
compact balls
norm-continuous linear functional are continuous

Weak topology is what we get when we remove the second requirement and weak star is what we get when we weaken the third (not all norm continuous functionals, just the ones that come from the primal space)
I have worked with minimization of functional rather than with PDEs, but there is a clear connection through the Euler-Lagrange equations.
There is a second way to get to these notions, more PDE based, which is as follows:
suppose you want to solve a PDE like $\partial_t u+\partial_x u^2=0$ for some
boundary condition. This is, in general, rather ugly (the characteristic lines intersect), but if we tweak it a little bit we get a much nicer one:
$$\partial_t u+\partial_x u^2=\varepsilon \Delta u.$$
The solutions $u_\varepsilon$ to this equation are indeed smooth and we would like to take some limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$. But then we incur in the same difficulties as above: we need to extend the space (as the limit is usually not smooth) and we need some weaker notion of convergence to make our proofs easier (first prove the limit exists in some weaker norm, then prove the convergence is actually strong) and the weak topology pops out in the same manner as above.

Thanks for your attention! I didn't manage to fully grasp what you explained (even though your explanation was very nice, I'm not that fast to get the ideas) and I need to think more about it.
this is the question that first made me to read about weak/weak* topologies. I'd really appreciate if share your ideas about this problem too.
I know you answered the question on weak*, still I can't see the probabilistic picture behind this question.

A similar approach works there as well: you want a topology such that 1) It is weaker than total variation 2) makes the space of probability complete 3)gives you some kind of compactness (after all, Prokhorov's theorem is very useful) 4) Allows you to have some results about the convergence of momenta (or truncated momenta).
